# how to connect mongodb via COMPASS is bastion host(jump) setup

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, ssh-tunnel

So I am using a bastion host(jump server) to connect to mongo db. I can use it via command line but I want to connect via compass.

So I am having an ec2-A(public) which uses ec2-B(private) to mongo db. I now how to do it on windows via putty but how to do it on mac??

Using this to connect jump server

```
ssh -i ~/B.pem -o "ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/A.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" ubuntu@1xx.xx.48.xx
```

and then mongo connection command.

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about). **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: Asking for help in setting up SSH tunneling ( even when used with tools *sometimes* associated with programming ) is still essentially a **networking related question** and therefore off-topic.